# How to change the position of the texture in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rust

I have a texture with the following texture coordinates

```rust
    vec![
        x,
        y,
        0.0, 0.0, // u,v
        layer,
        x + w,
        y,
        1.0, 0.0,
        layer,
        x + w,
        y + h,
        1.0, 1.0,
        layer,
        x,
        y + h,
        0.0, 1.0,
        layer,
    ]
```

[image]

How can I move the texture down by 10 pixels.

[image]

However I want to align my texture with the screen pixels, What calculation do I need to do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 ways to do this which heavily depend on how you are rendering your text. From the code you shared it seems you are rendering a quad that acts as the axis aligned bounding box of the character. In this case you need to figure out the dimensions of a pixel in normalized space.

### Working on texture coordinates (i.e normalized space is [0, 1])

A quick reminder on how normalized coordinates work. Let sw, sh denote the width and height of your window/canvas/drawing area in pixels. Let nw, nh be the normalized (i.e 0 to 1) coordinates of your quad. Then the screen coordinates of your quad are merely:

`w' = nw * sw`

`h = nh * sh`

The width of a single pixel is just 1/sw and the height is just 1/sh, thus moving the quad exactly 10 pixels down is just equivalent to adding the vector `(1/sw, -1/sh) * 10` to the 4 corners. Or you can convert to screen space, add (0, -10) and then renormalize by dividing each coordinate by the respective screen length.

For the second option, the math remains the same, but rather than doing it on the screen vertices, you do it with the uvs, but this is more relevant for when you want to offset the texture sampling without modifying the geometry, I added it for the sake of completeness.

### Working on screen coordinates (i.e normalized space is [-1, 1])

In this case one dimension is normalized to a length of 2 (since 1- (-1) = 2) rather than a length of 1 as in the above case. In other words the normalized coordinate in this scenario is `(x', y') = [(x,y) * 2 - (w, h)] / (w, h)`
You can verify that with the above formula (0,0) is mapped to (-1,-1) and (w,h) to (1,1).

This implies that the formula for relative offsets is just `(ox', oy') = 2 * (ox, oy) / (w, h)` since the constant term `(w,h)/(w,h)` will cancel out.

Comment: thanks Makogan, i tried `-1.0/SCR_HEIGHT * 10.0`, and it works. but when I compare with the result by the browser it seems short. but then I decided to multiply the result by 2. `1.0/SCR_HEIGHT * 10.0 * .0`, everything matches. why is that?

Comment: My math was incorrect, I accidentallly gave you the formula to convert to TEXURE coordinates, but you need the one for SCREEN coordinates, so let me correct my answer.

Comment: Added more information, sorry I originally led you astray

Comment: Thank you for making it clear to me. in the end I would choose this `(-1/SCR_HEIGHT * 10.0) * 2.0`. this kind of worked for me too